# Free Monad to generate blog feed in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, rss, free-monad

Suppose I need to add generate an RSS/Atom feed for a blog site. I am thinking about the "Feed Monad Interpreter" [pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/242795/what-is-the-free-monad-interpreter-pattern). That is, I would define a DSL with primitives `Blog` and `BlogPost`, a `Free monad`, which is just a tree of these primitives, and RSS/Atom "interpeters" that transform the `Free monad` tree to XML.

Does it make sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, because XML isn't an interpretation; it's a data structure, it has denotational rather than just operational semantics[1]. So you can define your primitives, and have a tree of them, and transform that pure tree to... another pure tree representing the XML. There's no need for the monad, this can just be a pure data transformation.

[1] Assuming I understand the terms correctly

Comment: Thank you. I think you are right. Now I'm thinking that even if I "interprete" the Free monad to fetch the blog data or render it as XML/HTML this approach does not make sense since the feed structure is fixed and very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I would recommend just using a template system and output (XML) strings rather than creating and transforming XML documents which can be pretty expensive for very little benefit in this use case.

Make sure you have a test suite that will parse the generated XML string to confirm that it's valid and won't break people consuming the feed, but aside from this, templates should work better!

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I am rendering blog data directly to string in RSS format. I am validating it with http://validator.w3.org/feed.